# Is PWA supposed to work only for SPA?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to convert a webview based app to PWA. This app isn't SPA, the app full page-reloads for links and also performs regular form POST submissions.

Something that I notice is that the scope (manifest.json) for POST seems to be outside of the app scope. When I submit a form POST, it opens like a page outside of the scope, then automatically closes it, and process the response from the submission in the background/standalone page.

manifest.json:

`{
  /* description/name/icons attributes */
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "dashboard/classes?utm_source=web_app_manifest",
}`

Is that expected?

Comment: It doesn't sound like the problem is related with PWA. Web Manifest is oblivious what is your JavaScript content handling strategy or if there is any JavaScript at all. I'd look for a problem somewhere where your POSTing code is.

Comment: @NOtherDev hm it seems that the problem is with HTTP redirects 301/302. If I click on a link /dashboard and it redirects to /dashboard/another-page or if I submit a form and the app redirects to another page it does the weird thing. It seems that from the response with 301/302 to the final location 200, the app in Android seems to be outside the scope. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was with the `redirect_to` from Rails, it was returning the Location header with HTTP, not HTTPS causing the URL to be outside of the app scope.

1. App (within scope) =>
2. Form submit (within scope) =>
3. Redirects to HTTP (outside scope) =>
4. CloudFlare Page Rule rewrite to HTTPS =>
5. App (within scope)